# Excel: Adding some numbers with some conditions

Tags: excel, date, sum, addition

I need to make a table in excel which automatically compute some sums. To begin with, I have the next table

```
   A            B
1  17/Sep/2014  20
2  22/Sep/2014  100
3  28/Sep/2014  50
4  02/Oct/2014  70
```

Column A has date format and B is a column which contains some numbers.

What function should I use to add only the numbers which are near a date from Sept 2014?

And on another table, on other Sheet, which will have 2 columns: one for the month, for example Sept, and near, on the next column the specific sum for that month, is there a function which can add a new row, with a new month, for example with November, when I add a new entry in the first table? (new entry: 02/Nov/2014  80)

I have tried a formula like this `=SUM(IF(MONTH(Sheet1!A:A)=9, Sheet1!B:B, 0))` but it doesn't work. It return a wrong sum.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

1) you can use this formula:

```
=SUM((MONTH(A1:A4)=9)*B1:B4)
```

You have to make it an array formula. Hold Ctrl+Shift pressed while hitting the final 'Return' to commit your formula. THIS IS IMPORTANT! Otherwise you get the wrong result. If you did it right your formula will be surrounded by curly brackets in the formula bar.

2) a formula (function) can't influence other cells than that one where it is in. If you want to influence other ranges of your sheets you have to use VBA what is a little bit more complicated - or let's say much more complicated. The easiest solution for your problem would be to prefill the columns on the second sheet up to a certain date, lets say December 2030. :-) It would be possible to make these future entries invisible as long there are no corresponding entries on the first sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function from your answer will search only for Sep 9, 2014. But I want to add all the sums from Sep. On the other hand, for my second question, I think that i will make a table with 2 columns one for the month which i will fill it with all the month and one for the sum, and in the function from the second columns i will check if the months match.